# CODEIGNITER: How do I fetch all of the rows that have a due date until tomorrow?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get all the data that have a duedate (tasks_duedate) until tomorrow.

```
  public function getNumDueTomorrowTasks(){
     $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day'));
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('tasks'); 
     $this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata('user_id'));  
     $this->db->where("tasks_duedate >", $date);
     $this->db->order_by("tasks_id", "desc");    
     $query_result=$this->db->get();
     $result=$query_result->result();
     $total = count ($result);
     return $total;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What results are you getting and how do they differ from the desired results? Do you have sample data and an expected total?

Comment: I get all of the the data that have a due-date sooner than today. For example: Today is 22.08.2016, i get the data from 01.12.2016, and i only want the data for tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't had chance to test this myself but, MySQL `Between` could come into play here.

```
public function getNumDueTomorrowTasks(){
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day'));
  $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('tasks'); 
  $this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata('user_id'));  
  $this->db->where('tasks_duedate BETWEEN "'. $today . '" and "'. $date .'"')
  $this->db->order_by("tasks_id", "desc");    
  $query_result=$this->db->get();
  $result=$query_result->result();
  $total = count ($result);
  return $total;
}
```

Comment: I get a Parsing Error from this " syntax error, unexpected 'between' (T_STRING)"

Comment: `$this->db->where("tasks_duedate BETWEEN $today AND $date");`
How about this?

If not this one may work:
`$this->db->where('tasks_duedate BETWEEN "'. $today . '" and "'. $date .'"');`

Comment: Thank you @Lero , the second code you gave me worked [$this->db->where('tasks_duedate BETWEEN "'. $today . '" and "'. $date .'"');]

Comment: @Developer updated my answer to correct the code too. Enjoy.